# Do Muslim martyrs really get 72 virgins in heaven?

Tags: death, jannah

I'm interested in knowing whether martyrs are promised 72 virgins in heaven.   I've already searched this site, and the question has not come up before.

Comment: The word 7, 70, 700, 7000, 70 000 should not be taken literally in Arabic. See 9:80

For instance, 
as regards the "seven heavens", it is to be borne in mind that in Arabic usage - and apparently in other Semitic languages as well - the number "seven" is often synonymous with "several" (see Lisan al-'Arab), just as "seventy" or "seven hundred" often means many or "very many" (Taj al-'Arus).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/22/46), a myrtyr is given 72 wives (not virgins) among 5 other othings

> That the Messenger of Allah () said: "There are six things with Allah
>   for the martyr. He is forgiven with the first flow of blood (he
>   suffers), he is shown his place in Paradise, he is protected from
>   punishment in the grave, secured from the greatest terror, the crown
>   of dignity is placed upon his head - and its gems are better than the
>   world and what is in it - he is married to seventy two wives along
>   Al-Huril-'Ayn of Paradise, and he may intercede for seventy of his
>   close relatives.

Could virgin come from a non authentic source? It is possible. Will update the answer if I find something relevant.

Comment: I think the virgin part is from the description of *hour al ein* in other sources, where they are described as "untouched by any other (man)"

Comment: Thanks @SystemDown down. I will look into that reference when I have time.

Comment: There is no authentic source that quotes about 72 wives. Its most probably a fluke in transliteration.

Comment: @AshwinSingh `zoja` in arabic means wives. That is correct translation. [Google link](https://translate.google.com/#ar/en/يُزَوَّجُ%20اثْنَتَيْنِ%20وَسَبْعِينَ%20زَوْجَةً)

Comment: The question is, why 72?

Comment: What? This makes no sense since girl obsession is a taboo

Comment: The word 7, 70, 700, 7000, 70 000 should not be taken literally in Arabic. See 9:80

Comment: As regards the "seven heavens", it is to be borne in mind that in Arabic usage - and apparently in other Semitic languages as well - the number "seven" is often synonymous with "several" (see Lisan al-'Arab), just as "seventy" or "seven hundred" often means many or "very many" (Taj al-'Arus).