# Do Muslim women get 72 partners in heaven?

Tags: jannah

Expanding on this answer here:
[Do Muslim martyrs really get 72 virgins in heaven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9523/do-muslim-martyrs-really-get-72-virgins-in-heaven)

Do women too get 72 husbands/partners in heaven, virgin or not.
If no, does that make heaven sexist?

Comment: well , women will be resurrected as women , and men will be resurrected as men. they will not be resurrected as neutral gender-less humans .. a man can have many women to reach maximum happiness, while the woman will reach it with only one husband. (in heaven) ... don't be  intimidated by labels.

Answer (score 1):

Arfan Shah at [Sheikhynotes.co.uk](http://www.sheikhynotes.co.uk/2010/01/womens-reward-in-paradise-in-islam.html) concludes:

> This leads us to say that this hadith includes women and Jinn, for the above reasons, to have multiple partners in paradise.

He comes to this conclusion based on [Qur'an 2:25](https://quran.com/2/25) (other translations at [Islam Awakened](http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/2/25/)):

> And give good tidings to **those who believe and do righteous deeds that they will have gardens [in Paradise]** beneath which rivers flow. Whenever they are provided with a provision of fruit therefrom, they will say, "This is what we were provided with before." And it is given to them in likeness. And **they will have therein purified spouses**, and they will abide therein eternally.

But precisely who these "spouses" are, and how many is unspecified.

The 72 virgin women for men is generally considered unreliable.  It's not in the Qur'an (see: [Misinterpretation about the 72 virgins](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33619/17163)).  However, there's ahadith such as [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1663](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/22/46), listed as hasan (good).  A [SeekersHub fatwa](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/07/29/72-virgins-for-martyrs-making-sense-of-one-of-the-rewards-of-paradise/) which addresses this topic writes:

> So in reality, **we cannot truly make “sense” of anything in Paradise** – our minds simply do not have the capacity. However Allah Most High has described its pleasures in language that we use, so as to give us approximations [however distant] based on pleasures we experience in this world. ...
>
> Notice that there is **no particular emphasis in the hadith on the 72 maidens** – it is one of several types of reward given to the martyr. Likewise, Muslims do not go about their day-to-day lives thinking of the maidens of Paradise; they are not obsessed with it the way they are often made out to be.

We're likewise in a similar situation with women.  It's possible, as lots of things are possible in paradise.  It's also possible paradise has something completely different in store.  Either way, whoever enters paradise will be satisfied.  This is a case of *Allah knows best*.

Answer (score -2):

Women will get "Hura" Beautiful young boy or boys. The number of Hurrah is undefined. It may be one or more.

Comment: Claims should be backed up with references.